# In C#, can an attribute be applied to a static class, method or property?

Tags: c#, static, attributes

Can an attribute be applied to a static class, method or property in c#? Like:

```
[MyAttribute]
public static MyMethods(string str) ...
```

Comment: Seems like an easy thing to try on your own....have you tried and failed?

Comment: Wouldn't that be `[My]`?

Comment: I echo Jason Webb's comment:  why haven't you just tried this yourself?

Comment: @Kobi: While you *can* abbreviate attribute names, you certainly don't have to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are really two questions here

**Is it possible for attributes in general to be applied to class, method's or properties?**

Yes attributes can validly target any of these constructs (and many others)

**Is it valid for a specific attribute to do so?**

That depends on the specific attribute.  Attributes can control which constructs they can be applied to via the `AttributeTargets` enum and hence make it illegal for a specific attribute to be applied to a specific construct.

For example the `ParamArrayAttribute` can only target parameters while the `ObsoleteAttribute` can target pretty much anything (except assemblies and maybe one other I'm missing)

Comment: However, even `AttributeTarget` cannot make an attribute invalid on a *static* item but valid on a *non-static* one of the same kind...

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can apply attribute to static class,method,property.

example:

```
[MyAttribute("hello")]
      public static string SayHello(string str)
      {
         return str;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Probably. Just try and see.

I wonder why you'd doubt it.

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything to the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Attribute if it can apply to a static class. Check out [AttributeTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets(v=VS.71).aspx). As such it is perfectly legal and allowed to decorate a static class or methods to with Attributes.